# Cauchy condensation test - do I have to prove $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My original question:

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n (\ln(n))^2}$$

I reached after a while to this (while using Cauchy condensation test)

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n (\ln(n))^2} < \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^2} $$

Now, since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$  converges, so does the original one.

But my question is, do I have to prove $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges? Or it is a sure fact? For all my exercises I didn't do it (neither did the practitioner), but just to make sure.

Is there any need? Or it is a sure fact?

Comment: Prove it! It will not hurt :). More seriously, the necessity to prove it heavily depend on the context. If you are a first year student, then it is probably a good idea, if you are an established math professor, then you probably don't need to prove it (but most certainly know how to do so, and you would not ask this question :) ).

Comment: Hehe, it is a bit problematic, it is a hard one, I learned one in my class, while using Cauchy (with epsilon > 0 and such... ), I saw at internet there is one with integral, but haven't learned it. But just to know, is it necessary?  But I guess I will do it just once to see I actually remember the proof. Thanks.

Comment: " But I guess I will do it just once to see I actually remember the proof" sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Hehe, okay, thanks :)

Comment: Proving the series converges is quite easy. Use e.g the ratio test.

Comment: @K.defaoite Ratio test will not work.

Comment: It's not a hard one Ben. There are of course easier ways, but if you used Condensation Theorem once with $\frac{1}{n \ln^2(n)}$ then why not try again with $\frac{1}{n^2}$? You'll end up with (I hope) a very known series.

Comment: @K.defaoite about the ratio test, you mean to prove ${1}/{n^2}$ with it? if so, I think you are right, actually forgot about it... I am very dumb lol.. how did I forget that simple solution for it...

Comment: Oh I just saw in the comments it wont work. then never mind, sorry about that comment.
about @DominikKutek , you mean to use it also on $\frac 1 {n^2}$? hmm, I will check it. and update if works.

Comment: @DominikKutek actually, you are right. I got the series: $\frac {1} {2^k}$ which is 100% converging because its half, with even smaller numbers. Thanks! Should I edit and add the solution or not do it? I want to mark an answer or just write one ( so people will know this question is good )

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable here that you answer and accept your own question, if you've just learned how to do it. Goodluck!

Comment: @DominikKutek Thanks!

Comment: Do not say $\sum\frac{1}{2^n}$ "is 100% converging".  Instead say: "is a convergent geometric series".

Comment: @GEdgar oh sorry, I am not that good in english, that is why I wrote it.
I will edit it now, thanks :)

Comment: @GEdgar Oh I didnt write it in the answer part, I wrote in chat, its all good.
Of course at answer I will not write like that :) but I will edit anyway, thanks. ( EDIT: I cant edit that comment for some reason )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to help, I reached the solution:
I do need to prove converges of: $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^2} $$
I am doing so by using once more Cauchy condensation test:
I will call $a_n$: $$a_{k}=\frac {1} {k^2} $$
Thus, by using Cauchy condensation test($ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^k} ⋅ a_{2^k}) $, we get:
$$ a_{2^k}=\frac {1} {n^2} $$
Then use the formula of Cauchy condensation test itself, and we get:
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1 ⋅ 2^k} {2^k ⋅ 2^k} $$
Which equals to:
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^k} $$
And here we see it.
The $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^k} $ converges.

Comment: You don't need to write $3*5;$ you can write $3\cdot5$ or $3\times5.$ An asterisk for that purpose is a workaround for occasions when you're restricted to characters on the keyboard (or in some cases, part of an affected style).

Comment: Thanks, fixed it, didn't notice it.

Comment: When in doubt, google "LaTeX symbols".

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes :) ( To be honest, I have a latex symbol site, that is how I know how to use latex here, but about the multiplication, did not even realize it... all those latex I did and multiplication not... its really idiotic what I did...

Answer (score 0):

Well at some point you'll have to decide what is part of your toolbox and what's still need to be proved. This will of course evolves as your own knowledge increases.

Some classical results that are also commonly accepted without proof at some point are:

- Geometric series $\sum c^n$ when $|c|<1$
- Geometric series with power factor $\sum n^a\,c^n$ when $|c|<1$ for any $a$
- Riemann series $\sum \frac 1{n^a}$ when $a>1$
- Bertrand series (which is a generalisation of your exercise) $\sum \frac 1{n^a\ln(n)^b\ln(\ln(n))^c\cdots}$ for $(a>1)$ or $(a=1,b>1)$ or $(a=b=1,c>1)$ or $\cdots$

Convergence for Riemann series is easily provable by comparison to an integral:

Indeed for $f\searrow$ we have

$$\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,dx\le\int_n^{n+1}f(n)\,dx\ =\ f(n)\ = \int_{n-1}^{n}f(n)\,dx\le\int_{n-1}^{n}f(x)\,dx$$

Apply to $f(n)=\frac 1{n^a}$ and since the anti-derivative of $x^{-a}$ is in $x^{1-a}$ it is convergent only for $1-a<0\iff a>1$ at infinity.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!!
About intergral, sadly, we have not learned it, and I guess we will not learn it at all ( weird, because usually people learn it first. but huge thanks for the enrichment!
Regarding the toolbox, I guess you are right, The last two were new to me ( we have not learned them yet also, but about the geometric you are right, and the one with factor also, thanks again )

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2} \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n(n-1)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_{n-1}^n \frac{dx}{x^2} = \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = 1 < +\infty.
$$

(Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2} = \frac {\pi^2} 6$ is a famous hard problem. It can be solved by elementary means, but only if you're very clever.)

**Postscript:** A variation on this theme:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n-1}^n \frac 1 {n^2} \, dx \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_{n-1}^n \frac 1 {x^2} \, dx= \cdots
$$

Comment: Oh we should learn it in Semester second. calculus 2, it is called Bazel formula if I am right? Our teacher told us we should not need to know it yet, but we know this problem :)
( Though we didn't learn integral test )